# gdb - watching global variable

Tags: gdb

I would like to watch a global variable before start of the main function. The one possible solution is to create a function which initialize a global variable and set a breakpoint on the function:

```
int Init()
{
    return 0;
}

int globalX = Init();

//gdb: break Init
//gdb: run
//gdb: awatch globalX
```

Is it possible to watch a global variable (before start of the main function) without defining a function breakpoint ? `watch globalX` doesn't work.

Comment: `watch globalX` works for me. What happens when you do it?

Comment: watchpoint is set, but after `run` gdb doesn't stop in the line where global function is defined: `int globalX = 0`;

Comment: Well, if you have a constant value as the global initialization, then this value isn't set when running the programm. It's already written with the value to the global variable section, in the executable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to watch a global variable (before start of the main function) without defining a function breakpoint ?

Yes. However, GDB will only stop when the value of the variable changes after the program starts, and for a variable that is initialized with a constant value the time it is set to that value is *before* the program starts.

More precisely:

```
int foo;
int bar = 42;
int baz = func();
```

The variable `foo` is allocated in the `.bss` section, and has value `0` before the first instruction in the process executes.

Likewise, variable `bar` is allocated in the `.data` section, and has value `42` before the first instruction (the corresponding location in the `.data` section has this value on disk, and it is simply `mmap`ed into the process before the process starts).

The variable `baz` is allocated in the `.data` section, and is *dynamically* initialized -- this is the only variable that actually changes its value after the process starts. You can `watch` that variable and observe where the initialization happens without setting a breakpoint on `func()`.